# Node.js REST service - express + backbone

Tags: node.js, rest, backbone.js, express

I am looking to build a site using backbone and express. I am new to this so I'd like to know if there's any difference between having both the express APIs and backbone client side code on the same server as opposed to having the APIs and client side code deployed on separate servers? If I put both on the same server, how do I structure the app to use both express and backbone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're still going to have to have some way to 'serve' the backbone files, so it's probably more convenient to keep it on the same server.  This is what I've used in the past

```
node_app
|-- apps
|    |-- authentication
|    |    |    |-- routes.coffee 
|-- bin
|-- public
|    |-- scripts
|    |    |-- models
|    |    |    |-- backbone_model_here.coffee
|    |    |-- views
|    |    |    |-- backbone_view_here.coffee
|    |    |-- collections
|    |    |    |-- backbone_collection_here.coffee
|    |    backbone_app.coffee

|    |-- stylesheets
|-- specs
|-- views
|    |-- authentication
|    |    |-- login.jade
server.js
```

also, this is a little opinionated however I like to separate different pieces of node logic into separate 'apps' e.g. an auth app or an image app